# Size of an $\epsilon$-net on n-qubit unitaries

Tags: matrices, metric-spaces, computational-geometry, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

I am currently reading through [Computational Quantum Entanglement](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.02783.pdf) paper and there is a following statement there in proof of Lemma 4.1

> We then use that an $\eta$-net (this is an $\epsilon$-net with different parameter) on $n(\lambda)$-qubit unitaries for the normalized Frobenius norm has size $(\frac{1}{\eta})^{\Omega(2^{2n(\lambda)})}$

This statement is used without any reference, yet it is not clear for me how this lower bound was achieved. Any pointers or reference material would be highly appreciated.